# prove that if $\lambda$ is a root of the cubic equation $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ (real or complex), then $| \lambda | \leq 1.$

Tags: polynomials

> Let $a,b,c$ be three real numbers such that $1 \geq a \geq b \geq c \geq 0$. prove that if $\lambda$ is a root of the cubic equation $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ (real or complex), then $| \lambda | \leq 1.$

---

I [found](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h55426p344715) the following solution,

> $P(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ If $|z| > 1$ then $|(z-1) \times P(z)| \geq |z|^4 - ( (1-a)|z^3| + (a-b)|z|^2 + (b-c)|z| + c) > 0$
> So every roots $z$ are such as $|z| \leq 1$

---

I understand $zP(z)-P(z)= z^4 + z^3(a-1)+z^2 (b-a)+z(c-b)$
I'm not able to understand how they got the inequality $$|(z-1) \times P(z)| \geq |z|^4 - ( (1-a)|z^3| + (a-b)|z|^2 + (b-c)|z| + c) > 0$$

Comment: Triangle inequality.

Comment: Right, add the subtracted expression to both sides and you get $$|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|+|E|\geq |A+B+C+D+E|,$$ for some set of values $A,B,C,D,E.$